# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while finding prime Number and creating array with it

Tags: java, arrays, exception, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

**Target** - find all primeNumbers and create array with it
**What was done** - 
created method primeReturner - return true if number prime -

```
    private static boolean primeReturner (int i){
    for (int j=2;j<i; j++){
        if (i%j==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

created method for creating numbers with prime numbers

```
    private static void simpleArray()  {
    int []a = new int [100];
    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=2;
    for (int i=2; i<a.length; i++){
        if (primeReturner(i)==true){
            a[i]=i;
            i++;
            }
    }
}
```

Problem - i get some errors during creating array - some of item from array 0 and some its ok... and some times it return errors...

**Questing** - what wrong with my method simpleArray?

---

A little bit modify code - now it recognize all prime numbers and create array with it, but after adding 100th item in to array i get errors

code

```
private static void simpleArray()  {
    int []a = new int [100];
    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=2;
    int count=2;
    while (count<100)
    for (int i=3; ; ++i){
        if (primeReturner(i)==true){
            a[count]=i;
            count++;
            }
    }
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++){
        System.out.print(" " + a[j]);
    }
}
private static boolean primeReturner (int i){
    for (int j=2;j<i; j++){
        if (i%j==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and main function
    public class Exercise_1 {
        private static int select;

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Menu:");
    ....
    System.out.println("Array with simple numbers - enter 7");
    select = getNumber ();

    switch (select){
    .....
    case 7:{
        simpleArray();
    }
    }
}
```

As result all array with prime number succsesfull created
[image]
 but during printing this array i get **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException errors**...

How to resolve this error?

Comment: during running some java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: No exceptions for me.  Could you please publish complete code with `main` method?  In code you provided, in all places where array is accessed, it is guaranteed that index is below array length.

Comment: Optimization.suggestions: in `primeReturner (int i)` you can improve the loop: `int  upperbound=Math.sqrt(i); for (int j=2;j<=upperbound; j++)`. And if you want to have all prime number up to a given value, you should consider implementing the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 0):

You do `i++` in your `if(primeReturner(i)) == true)` block. This is in addition to the `for` loop `i++`. You'll most likely get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because your `i` index will reach a value greater than 100, which is your array max size. Remove that `i++` in the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that you use the same variable to index in your array (ie. the index of the n-th prime), and the value of the prime. So the array constructed in `simpleArray` will have a zero value if the index is non-prime or the value `i` if it is prime. You need a second index if you want a fully packed array:

```
private static void simpleArray()  {
    int []a = new int [100];
    a[0] = 2; // by definition 1 is not prime
    int i = 1;
    int possible_prime = 3;
    while (i < a.length) {
        if (primeReturner(possible_prime)) {
            a[i++]=possible_prime;
        }
        possible_prime++;
    }
}
```

For discussion of the primality of one, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Primality_of_one).

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i=2; i<a.length; i++){
        if (primeReturner(i)==true){
            a[i]=i;
            i++;
            }
    }
```

This is where the problem lies... remove i++ from the code

so here:

```
for (int i=2; i<a.length; i++){
    if (primeReturner(i)==true){
        a[i]=i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find error - need to stop loop with i by adding limit
So, final code is

```
private static void simpleArray()  {
    int []a = new int [100];
    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=2;
    int count=2;
    while (count<100){
    for (int i=3;**i<524** ; ++i){
        if (primeReturner(i)==true){
            a[count]=i;
            count++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (count=0; count<a.length; count++){
        System.out.print(" " + a[count]);
    }
}
```

Think 'i<524' not the best variant, later will try to find somthing better =)
thanks to all.